# python DictReader subclassing

Tags: python, csv, subclassing

This is my first attempt about subclassing, so I need some hints from you experts..
I'm trying to subclass csv.DictReader / Writer to have a higher level class to do something like this :

```
a = CsvRdr('filename.csv')

for row in a.rows:
    # do something with dict returned in row

a.close()
```

I've come up with a subclass like this :

```
class CsvRdr(csv.DictReader):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__fo = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.__delim = '\t'
        self.rows = csv.DictReader(self.__fo, self.__delim)
        self.rows.__init__(self.__fo, self.__del)
    def close(self):
       self.__fo.close()
```

but when I do :

```
for i in a.rows:
    print i
```

it returns an unformatted dict containing the delimiter \t as key :

```
{'\t': 'seriesid\tseriesname\tstatus\tquality\tgroup\tpath'}
{'\t': '80337\tMad Men\tAiring\thdtv\tTV Shows\t/share/MD0_DATA/SORT/TV Shows/Mad Men'}
{'\t': '271910\tHalt and Catch Fire\tHiatus\thdtv\tTV Shows\t/share/MD0_DATA/SORT/TV
```

instead of a dict containing the proper fieldnames and the relative values splitted by delimiter

But when I'm going to instantiate DictReader from another function, all that i need to do is :

```
fo = open(filename, 'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(fo, delimiter='\t')
```

and the reader object correctly gives you the desired output.

Any suggestion ?
I've not clear in my mind the subclassing process, and what'ive found online till now didn't help me.

TIA
Enrico

Comment: a quick thought ... does your __init__ need to call the __init__ of the csv.DictReader?

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code would barf with an `AttributeError`, you have `self._del` when you mean to have `self._delim`.

Beyond that, your other issue is that you invoke the constructor incorrectly:

```
self.rows = csv.DictReader(self.__fo, self.__delim)
```

should be

```
self.rows = csv.DictReader(self.__fo, delimiter = self.__delim)
```

Looking at the constructor signature for `DictReader` we see what actually happened:

```
csv.DictReader(self, f, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)
```

Your `self.__delim` argument was set to the `fieldnames` parameter. This is what Python (2.7 anyway) does by default when you give a non-keyword position argument to a function that has only keyword arguments remaining. It fills in the next keyword argument in the signature using the positional argument.

So you're telling `DictReader` "Hey this CSV has only one column, and it's name is '\t'". So `DictReader` does the logical thing which is to only have one value per row, that value being the entire line.

Finally this line:

```
self.rows.__init__(self.__fo, self.__del)
```

Isn't doing anything, you are just repeating the constructor call in a more explicit way.

Here's how I would re-write what you were trying to do:

```
class CsvRdr(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__fo = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.__delim = '\t'
        self.rows = csv.DictReader(self.__fo, delimiter = self.__delim)

    def close(self):
       self.__fo.close()
```

Notice I change `csv.DictReader` to `object`, this is because this pattern you are using is actually delegation and not subclassing or inheritance. You are just setting one of your objects attributes to an instance of the class you are interested in using, and your methods just call that instance's methods in more convenient ways.

Comment: Thanks qww*, this attempt was the result of replicating the general instructions that I found with the interpreter.
I noticed that '\t' was taken as fieldname instead of delimiter, but  I thought that delimiter was positional as second parameter.
Silly mistake, but I'm doing this to learn.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved in this way :

```
class CsvRdr(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, delimiter=None):
        self.__fo = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.__delim = ( delimiter if delimiter else '\t' )
        self.__rows = csv.DictReader(self.__fo, delimiter = self.__delim)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__rows
    def close(self):
        self.__fo.close()
```

Class called by this function :

```
def CsvRead(filename):
    try:
         reader = CsvRdr(filename)
         return reader
    except IOError, e:
         print "Error reading file : %s ERROR=%s" % (filename, e)
         sys.exit(2)
```

In this second attempt, I added the **iter** magic method to mimic the original behaviour of Csv.DictReader, so you can loop thru data in the usual way, instead of using object.rows method :

```
reader = CsvRead(catalog)
seriesnames = [ row['seriesname'].lower() for row in reader ]
reader.close()
```